# Write in a .txt file in Python with class name which varies (0 to N)

Tags: python

I have a class named myClass which contains some attributes (attribute0, attibute1...).

I've created N myClass (myClass0, myClass1...).

To write in a .txt file myClass0.attribute0:

```
fichier = open("myFile.txt", "a")
fichier.write("{}".format(myClass0.attribute0))
```

I want to write in the file myFile.txt myClassN.attribute0 with N for 0 to 9:

```
fichier = open("myFile.txt", "a")
fichier.write("{}".format(myClass0.attribute0))
fichier.write("{}".format(myClass1.attribute0))
.
.
.
fichier.write("{}".format(myClass9.attribute0))
```

How to do it in a loop?

Comment: Store `myClassN` in a list.

Comment: If the classes are so similar that they can be named `MyClass0`, `MyClass1` etc you would be better of creating just `MyClass` and storing 0..N as an attribute called `MyClass.subclass`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop code only - please replace your `.write` lines with this:

```
class_list = [myClass0, myClass1, myClass2 ,etc.]
for instance in class_list:
    myFile.append("{}".format(instance.attribute0))
```

Also to clarify, if you are trying to have all the class names in one file you cannot use the .write file method as it overwrites anything already in the file - this is why I used .append instead as it adds to an existing file.

*Just as a side note it is generally preferred to use

`with open(file_name) as my_file:
      # do stuff here`

instead of attaching your open file to a variable.

It is also accepted practice to use underscores to separate words in variable names, instead of camel case (wordWord) in Python as showed in PEP8:

"Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability. Variable names follow the same convention as function names."*

Comment: Thanks for the reformat, for some reason even after using correct indentation it reverted to without indentation, is that normal?